# Where is beamer.sty?

Tags: beamer, mactex, presentations

Every time I try to make a `beamer` presentation (using the version that came with my TeX distribution), it asks me for `beamer.sty`. Which isn't in the official repo for `beamer`. Arrgh. Has anybody got a solution?

Comment: Complementary to the answers search for `beamer.cls` and you'll find it which means latex interprets it as a class even though your TeX distro downloads it as a package.

Comment: `cd /usr/local/texlive/2012` and then `find -name "*.cls"|grep 'beamer'`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`beamer`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamer) is a LaTeX class not a package.
You activate it with

```
\documentclass{beamer}
```

Comment: Ahem. Isn't it added by a package?

Comment: `while (true) { it is_not_ a package };`

Comment: @rake there us a distinction between "package" as used by miktex or texlive package managers where "package" means any collection of files installed as a unit, and "package" as meant by latex `\usepackage`. To latex beamer is a class loaded with `\documentclass` not a package loaded with `\usepackage`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yeah, but do you need to `\usepackage{beamer}` to get it to work? After all it isn't a standard class.

Comment: no as been said several times now it wont work with usepackage because it is a class. cls file not a package. sty file